# How to use flame type charts?

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcarts type=flame while loading hightcarts,-more,suburst modules but I get an error.

"Highcharts error #17: [www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=flame](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=flame)

- missingModuleFor: flame"

Comment: Hi @Иван Кондратьев, Are you sure that `highcharts-more` and `sunburst` modules are correctly loaded and initialized? As you can see in this live example: https://jsfiddle.net/36uamy2v/ only these modules are required.

Comment: Yes that's right, I am downloading these two modules, my highcharts is 9.0.1.1.1

Comment: Ok, so could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor?

Comment: unfortunately the problem is localized. I have a CDN and on the client I do an import for highcarts,-more,-sunburst.
When I do this, the error from the track crashes.

Comment: Could you share at least your chart options? You probably have a situation similar to this one: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pxnv58qo/ - the required modules are added, but the plugin which adds the flame series is missing. Example with the plugin: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7rvhuqzy/

Comment: What is the idea behind how this plugin works? What is it for? How do I download it? What is H?

Comment: Please check the docs about extending Highcharts: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts The plugin just creates `flame` series type based on the `columnrange` one. `H` is just an argument passed to the function and its value is `Highcharts`.